# blazor: (bigger) images picked by the user are only displayed half, rest is filled with blank

Tags: html, css, blazor

i am new to blazor, and i worked on a little image picker component:

```
        <div hidden="@memePicVisible" class="container2">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img src="@imageDataUrl">
            </div>
        </div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public ImageType ImgType { get; set; }


    private string imageDataUrl;

    public static string ImageResult = "";

    private async Task HandleFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = e.File;

        if (file != null)
        {
            using var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
            var buffer = new byte[file.Size];
            await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, (int)file.Size);

            // Convert the image bytes to a base64 data URL
            imageDataUrl = $"data:{file.ContentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";

            var res = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
            ImageResult = res;

            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    public enum ImageType
    {
        AnzeigenBild,
        OfferPic, 
    }

}


public static string ToBase64String(byte[] inArray)
{
    if (inArray == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inArray));
    }
    return ToBase64String(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(inArray), Base64FormattingOptions.None);
}
```

Some images loaded with this function show up fine, but some wont. And its always the same result with the same input images.
For instance:

Image is always only shown half:

[image: Only half is filled. Rest is filled by some sort of error?]

Image is always shown fine.
[image: Image is shown fine.]

Anyone can help me out?

EDIT:

I have noticed that the images that only show half, sometimes show more or less. So its not always static, but for the images that show up fine; they ALWAYS show fine.

ALSO: it seems to be size realted. the bigger the image is that is shown, the more unlikey it seems to be shown in full...

Comment: How big is the large picture? Are you violating Blazors message size if you are using Blazor server?

Comment: 200kb ... i dont know?

Comment: It's almost certainly size of the base64 string - [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#upload-image-preview) - they explain how to do this with a little bit of javascript to create an objecturl